# android app is going to background on event?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have designed an app which is having the language change event(Localization) that is working fine, with JellyBean and LolliPop. Same android .apk is not launching with the kitkat.

Comment: your manifest min or max sdk api level is not correct what is your min and max api level of sdk

Comment: check minSdk version in your manifest.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: but why its working with lollipop and marshmallow